# Using forEach to loop through a selection of button classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to implement the delete button for the simple vanilla JS note app below. When I apply the query selector to the single "delete-button" class it is only able to select the first appended child, and when querySelectorAll is used it iterates into the click function for each additional button that's on the page at the time.

Should I be using for Each here? What am I doing wrong in the deleteBtn call towards the bottom? Sorry if the code is messy!

```
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");
const noteArea = document.querySelector(".modal");


let notes = [];


function addNoteHandler() {
    //pull value from note box
    let title = document.querySelector("#note-title").value;
    let note = document.querySelector("#textBox").value;
    
    //check if boxes are empty and push note contents to array (obj?)
    if (note !== "" && title !== "") {
    notes.push(title, note);

    //create note card items
    let containerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let titleModal = document.createElement("h6");
    let noteModal = document.createElement("p");
    let viewButton = document.createElement("button");
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    let buttonDiv = document.createElement("div");

    //define content and classes
    containerDiv.className = "card-class";
    titleModal.className = "card-header";
    titleModal.innerText = `${title}`;
    noteModal.className = "modal-p";
    
    viewButton.innerText = "View Note";
    viewButton.className = "expand-modal";

    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete Note";
    deleteButton.className = "delete-button";

    //create text node that houses the p
    let textBox = document.createTextNode(note);


    //append items to container div
    noteModal.appendChild(textBox);
    
    containerDiv.appendChild(titleModal);
    containerDiv.appendChild(noteModal);
    buttonDiv.appendChild(viewButton);
    buttonDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);
    containerDiv.appendChild(buttonDiv);
    noteArea.appendChild(containerDiv);
    // noteModal.appendChild(textBox);
    // noteArea.appendChild(noteModal);
    } else {
        alert("Please Enter A Note First!")
    } 

       //define delete button
    const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-button").forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener("click", q => {
            console.log("clicked");
        })
    });
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", addNoteHandler);
```

Comment: `deleteBtn` will contain `undefined`. You must either assign a value to `deleteBtn` or use the `forEach()` method - but not both.

Comment: The function call isn't on the deleteBtn constant though, it's on the inner (".delete-button") class. I haven't received an undefined error, just the "clicked" console log being replicated for each button present on the page.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you just want to delete the note when delete note button is clicked. you should target the containerDiv using the parent property and should be able to remove the note. see example.

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector(".add-button");
const noteArea = document.querySelector(".modal");


let notes = [];


function addNoteHandler() {
  //pull value from note box
  let title = document.querySelector("#note-title").value;
  let note = document.querySelector("#textBox").value;

  //check if boxes are empty and push note contents to array (obj?)
  if (note !== "" && title !== "") {
    notes.push(title, note);

    //create note card items
    let containerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    let titleModal = document.createElement("h6");
    let noteModal = document.createElement("p");
    let viewButton = document.createElement("button");
    let deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    let buttonDiv = document.createElement("div");

    //define content and classes
    containerDiv.className = "card-class";
    titleModal.className = "card-header";
    titleModal.innerText = `${title}`;
    noteModal.className = "modal-p";

    viewButton.innerText = "View Note";
    viewButton.className = "expand-modal";

    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete Note";
    deleteButton.className = "delete-button";

    //create text node that houses the p
    let textBox = document.createTextNode(note);


    //append items to container div
    noteModal.appendChild(textBox);

    containerDiv.appendChild(titleModal);
    containerDiv.appendChild(noteModal);
    buttonDiv.appendChild(viewButton);
    buttonDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);
    containerDiv.appendChild(buttonDiv);
    noteArea.appendChild(containerDiv);
    // noteModal.appendChild(textBox);
    // noteArea.appendChild(noteModal);
  } else {
    alert("Please Enter A Note First!")
  }

  //define delete button
  const deleteBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".delete-button").forEach(e => {
    e.addEventListener("click", q => {
      q.toElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
    })
  });
}
debugger;
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addNoteHandler);
```

```html
Title<input id="note-title"> Content
<input id="textBox">

<button class="add-button">Click Here</button>
<div class="modal"> </div>
```